# Saving data to local storage using vuex persisted state

Tags: vuejs2, vuex, nuxt.js, vuex-modules

I'm currently using this plugin [vuex-persistedstate](https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate)

and I would like to use it with Vuex module of my Nuxt app.

Basically I have a login module if success, then store the `authToken` coming from the response to `localStorage`

Here's my code:

```
import axios from "axios";
import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate';

export const state = () => ({
  signInAttrs: {
    email: "",
    password: ""
  },
  authToken: ""
});

export const mutations = {
  SET_AUTH_TOKEN(state, token) {
    state.authToken = token;


    createPersistedState({
      key: 'admin-auth-key',
      paths: [],
      reducer: state => ({
        authToken: '123123123'
      })
    })(store);
  }
};

export const actions = {
  signInAdmin({ commit }, context) {
    return axios.post(`${process.env.BASE_URL}/sign_in`, {
      email: context.email,
      password: context.password
    }).then(response => {
      commit('SET_AUTH_TOKEN', response.data.headers.token);
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(`failed ${error}`);
    });
  }
};

export const getters = {
  signInAttrs(state) {
    return state.signInAttrs;
  },
  authToken(state) {
    return state.authToken;
  }
};
```

Inside the mutations there's `SET_AUTH_TOKEN` that receives the token as the parameter from API. How can I save it to localStorage?

Answer (score 3):

I think you're misunderstanding usage of vuex-persistedstate. Once you add it to Store plugins (`plugins: [createPersistedState()]`), it automatically updates localStorage variable `vuex` with a copy of your store on each mutation commit (see [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/80k4m2598)). So your token should be inside `vuex.authToken` in `localStorage` already.

If you want to simply store a variable with custom name you can do it without plugins: `localStorage.setItem('key', 'value')`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage).

Comment: Do not forget to include Vuex-persistedstate as a Nuxt plugin (documented on GitHub). You can also use the option `path` for `createPersistedState` to filter what parts of your Vuex state to be persisted.